# How to interpret feature importance in a decision tree after applying Factor Analysis

Tags: pca, feature-selection, scikit-learn, cart, factor-analysis

I'm using SKlearn to apply [Factor Analysis (FA)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.FactorAnalysis.html) to my data before training a [Decision Tree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html).

I then want to do an importance analysis. If I had not applied FA to my data, I could just call clf.feature_importances_() on the decision tree.

However, now, that would provide the importance of each factor-analyzed-feature.

How would I go about casting those importances back to the original features?

If the answer is easier with PCA, I can go with that.

Comment: This is not compatible, FA gives you factors, this is not data anymore, you cannot use this is a decision tree.